# Payne gas furnace, model # PY3GNAA36090AATP.

Tags: furnace

Indoor fan blows continually, with 4 flashes on control board

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need some more information about this: how did it start? What else does the furnace do? What do you get when you google "4 flashes on Payne gas furnace control board"?

Answer (score 1):

### It sounds like a choked indoor fan

A four-flash code on the control for your furnace (PY3G--A) means that the high limit is tripping repeatedly and cutting out combustion.  The continuously running blower is a sign that the control board is calling for fan due to the high plenum temperatures that aren't going away, as well.  I would check for a clogged filter or other airflow restriction that's keeping things from working properly. If this is a new install, then you'll have to get the HVAC contractor back out and beat them upside the head with a Manual D until they can install ductwork with low enough static pressure losses to keep the furnace happy.